# Django keeps replacing content on the view

Tags: python, django

I have multiple text files in a folder, which all of them created dynamically from Cisco Switches. I want to read each file and display on the web. So I have this code:

```
def idf(request):
    context = {}

    all_files = os.listdir("devices/")
    for i in all_files:
        with open(i, 'r') as readFile:
            switch_ports = readFile.readlines()
            print(switch_ports)
            readFile.close()

            context.update({'switch_ports': switch_ports})
    return render(request, 'idf.html', context)
```

The problem is, it loops through the function, and only renders the last file. So it is basically replacing the content. How can I keep all of them? So they just keep appending to the last file?

Here is the template:

```
        {% block everyDevice %}

        {% block switch_ports %}
            
            <h1>{{ everyDevice }}</h1> 
            {% for result in switch_ports %}
            <p>{{ result }}</p>

            {% endfor %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% endblock %}
    </main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You override the key in your context on every iteration of the loop, store the data in a list (or whatever is appropriate) and pass that list to your context after the loop

```
def idf(request):
    switch_ports = []
    all_files = os.listdir("devices/")
    for i in all_files:
        with open(i, 'r') as readFile:
            switch_ports.append(readFile.read())
    return render(request, 'idf.html', {'switch_ports': switch_ports})
```

Use a `pre` tag to output the results as this will format the text with a monospace font and most likely look how you want. Also use `read()` instead of `readlines()` to get the raw txt instead of a list of lines

```
    {% for result in switch_ports %}
        <pre>{{ result }}</pre>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: it worked. But it blew up the text format. Can I keep the format coming from text file?

Comment: @user15109593 can you add your template to the question? The answer depends on how you use the data in your template

Comment: Just added the template.

Comment: @user15109593 made an edit, I think you should probably use a `<pre>` tag in your template to format the result and you should read the entire file instead of reading the lines

Answer (score 0):

`context.update({"switch_ports": switch_ports})` is going to replace the existing "switch_ports" with whatever the latest iteration value is at that time so your issue makes perfect sense.

My recommendation would be to use a [list append](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and then [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to achieve the desired result.

```py
def idf(request):
    context = {}
    switch_ports = []

    all_files = os.listdir("devices/")
    for i in all_files:
        with open(i, 'r') as readFile:
            switch_port = readFile.readlines()
            print(switch_port)
            switch_ports.append(switch_port)
            readFile.close()

    context.update({'switch_ports': "".join(switch_ports)})
    return render(request, 'idf.html', context)
```

If you would like your file contents to be joined/separated by something other than "", you can use a different separator as outlined in the join documentation.

Comment: You know all text files are having a very good format which I wanna keep. When I use append, it will lose the format. Is there any way to keep the format coming from text file?